# Can't pull text field value into Backend. Django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, forms

I'm using a simple HTML form to pass data to my Django app's backend.

I'm not using a Django form because I don't need to update the database.

However, I'm unable to pull data from the form.

HTML code:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay='0.8s'>
            <input type="text" id="fullname" required>
        </div>      
        <button onclick="SendMessage()">Send Your Message</button>
    </div>
    <div id="output"></div>
</form>
```

JQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SendMessage() {
        // $('.ajaxProgress').show();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ' {% url "payligent:send_message" %} ',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{csrf_token}}',
                fullname: $('#fullname').val()
            },
            success: function (json) {
                $('output').html(json.message);
                $('ajaxProgress').hide();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

view:

```
def send_message(request):
    test = request.POST.get('fullname')
    response_data = {}
    try:
        response_data['message'] = test
    except:
        response_data['message'] = 'Oh Snap! message was not sent correctly'
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type='text/html')
```

When I browse into: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/sendmessage/` I get `null` instead of the name I filled in the form:

```
{"message": null}
```

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYNDXrLu57k) tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to change your view, a little bit, change the line,

```
test = request.POST['fullname']
```

`dict.get()` method returns a default value of `''`, if the `dict` doesn't contain the key specified. So, `try-except` can't catch the exception.
But, by accessing the key value like this, raises the `KeyError` exception if not exists.

Try your view maybe something like this,

```
def send_message(request):
response_data = {}
try:
    response_data['message'] = request.POST['fullname']
except:
    response_data['message'] = 'Oh Snap! message was not sent correctly'
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type='text/html')
```

Answer (score 1):

`request.POST` only work if under request post, but if you browse into `http://127.0.0.1:8000/sendmessage/` of course you get null because you under `request.GET` not `request.POST`.

One again, here you missed `name="fullname"`.

Hope this useful for u;

```
<form id="form-message" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay='0.8s'>
      <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" required>
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Send Your Message</button>
  </div>
  <div id="output"></div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var form = $('#form-message');
  var output = $('#output');

  form.submit(function () {
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "{% url 'payligent:send_message' %}",
          data: form.serialize(),
          success: function(message) {
            output.html(message);
          },
          error: function(message) {
            output.html(message);
          }
      });
      return false;
  });
</script>
```

In your `views.py`:

```
def send_message(request):
    response_data = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fullname = request.POST.get('fullname', None)
        if fullname is not None:
            response_data['message'] = fullname
        else:
            response_data['message'] = 'Oh Snap! message was not sent correctly'
    else:
        response_data['message'] = 'Request POST only!'
    return return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems I only forgot to add the "#" sign to the output div. So it should be:

```
$('#output').html(json.message);
```

Instead of:

```
$('output').html(json.message);
```